# How to debug a sitefinity project

Tags: sitefinity

My sitefinity project that runs on 5.2 is deployed on IIS 7.0.
I am running into an error.
How do i debug this as I cannot run this through visual studio either.
Please help so that i can set breakpoints like i do in my normal asp.net code and check the debug variables. Is this possible for a istefinity project that runs on IIUS 7.0?
Please help.

Comment: is the error in the Sitefinity code, or in a custom module that you have developed?

Answer (score 1):

If IIS is on the same machine as Visual Studio, you can debug>Attach to Process>w3wp

If IIS is on a remote machine, you will need to go the "remote debugging" route. Install the remote debugging server bits on the IIS machine, run them, and then attach to them from your Visual Studio install. See: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/visual_studio_remote_debugging.html for more details.

Note that you don't really want to do this on a production system, as you might freeze the w3wp at a specific breakpoint as you troubleshoot, blocking other visitors from being served.